# Does translating images' file names in a multilingual website matter for SEO?

Tags: seo, images, multilingual, filenames

I'm taking care of a website's SEO. Its languages are Portuguese and Spanish. Usually, I just use English for programming, including files naming.

In order to take advantage of boost rank that meaningful images' file names can provide, will I have to translate its names to both Portuguese and Spanish, either by duplicating the files or going with a sever side rewrite approach?